# How to solve "Bad operand type" for the function below in Java?

Tags: java, bit-manipulation

Basically I wanted to try bitwise manipulation in Java, and it seems that C and Java do not handle the bits in the same way.

```
public static boolean checkIsPowerOfTwo(int x) {
    return ( !(x & (x-1)) );
}
```

This function, [taken from here](http://www.exploringbinary.com/ten-ways-to-check-if-an-integer-is-a-power-of-two-in-c/) is not working as expected in Java, so my understanding of bitwise operators is clearly not right for Java.

The error I get is

```
CheckIsPowerOfGivenNumber.java:13: error: bad operand type int for unary operator '!'
return ( !(x & (x-1)) );
         ^
```

How can I correct this?

Comment: That is c code, not Java. What have you found about operators in Java. Why do you expect it to work?

Comment: `!` is a boolean operator. You're trying to apply it on an integer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java type system is more strict comparing to C. In particular it does not perform automatic conversion from `int` to `boolean` (which actually helps to prevent many stupid bugs). The `!` operator in Java is applicable for boolean type only. Use `==` operator to explicitly compare the value with `0`:

```
public static boolean checkIsPowerOfTwo(int x) {
    return (x & (x-1)) == 0;
}
```

Actually `(x & (x-1)) == 0` is a valid C code as well, but looks definitely less cryptic. I would recommend writing on C this way as well.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the bitwise part is correct the problem is ! is a logical not  --- the bitwise not (comm operator is ~.  Having said that you still have the probem of convert your int to a boolean.

```
    return ((~(x &(x-1)) == 0);
```

Comment: That doesn't work, it compiles but changing `!something` to `~something == 0` is obviously wrong